# How to fix 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function' when add jquery 3.2.1 library in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

First, I want to make a datepicker, but when I add the jquery.min.js library I get an error 'daterangepicker is not a function' how to fix it?

I already tried removing the jquery.min.js library but what appeared was 't is not a function'

in pages dashboard blade.php

```
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
});
</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',

            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });

    });
</script>
```

this is dashboard.php  to call function lib

```
 public function dashboard()
    {
        $pages['view'] = 'pages.dashboard.dashboard';


        $data['css'] = $this->css_dashboard();
        $data['js'] = $this->js_dashboard();
        $data['js'] = array_merge($this->js_dashboard(),[]);

        $data['icon'] = 'icon-home';
        $data['parent'] = 'Dashboard';

        $data['view'] = $this->page($pages);
        return $data;
    }
```

and this is controller.php to call library

```
public function css_dashboard()
    {
        $css = array(
            'jamtangan/css/library/daterangepicker.css',
        );
        return $css;
    }

    public function js_dashboard()
    {
        $js = array(
            'jamtangan/js/library/chart.js',
            'jamtangan/js/library/daterangepicker.min.js',
            'jamtangan/js/library/moment.min.js'
            'jamtangan/js/library/jquery.min.js'
        );
        return $js;
    }
```

Comment: Always jquery should be at the top, move 'jamtangan/js/library/jquery.min.js' to top of array.

Comment: it works thank you